# How to sort an xml document with respect to two or three elements inside a node

Tags: c#, xml

How do I sort a whole XML document with respect to one or more elements inside a particular node and store that as a new XML file.
For ex.- "INPUT FILE"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ABCD>
    <XYZ>
      <LEVEL>0</LEVEL>
      <ITEM>331-4437</ITEM>
      <QTY>1</QTY>
      <REV>A02-00</REV>
      <STATUS>B</STATUS>
      <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
        <XYZ>
            <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
            <PARENT_ITEM>331-4437</PARENT_ITEM>
            <ITEM>1234</ITEM>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
            <REV>A02-00</REV>
            <STATUS>B</STATUS>
            <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
        </XYZ>
        <XYZ>
            <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
            <PARENT_ITEM>331-4437</PARENT_ITEM>
            <ITEM>0234</ITEM>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
            <REV>A02-00</REV>
            <STATUS>B</STATUS>
            <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
            <SOMETHING>fgh</SOMETHING>
        </XYZ>
    </XYZ>
    <XYZ>
      <LEVEL>0</LEVEL>
      <ITEM>2240123</ITEM>
      <QTY>1</QTY>
      <REV>A02-00</REV>
      <STATUS>B</STATUS>
      <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
      <SOMETHING>fgh</SOMETHING>
    </XYZ>
</ABCD>
```

How can i sort this above xml according to level&item&parent item(if it is present). I am new to C# so please help me with some piece of code.
"OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ABCD>
   <XYZ>
      <LEVEL>0</LEVEL>
      <ITEM>2240123</ITEM>
      <QTY>1</QTY>
      <REV>A02-00</REV>
      <STATUS>B</STATUS>
      <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
      <SOMETHING>fgh</SOMETHING>
    </XYZ>
    <XYZ>
      <LEVEL>0</LEVEL>
      <ITEM>331-4437</ITEM>
      <QTY>1</QTY>
      <REV>A02-00</REV>
      <STATUS>B</STATUS>
      <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
      <XYZ>
            <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
            <PARENT_ITEM>331-4437</PARENT_ITEM>
            <ITEM>0234</ITEM>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
            <REV>A02-00</REV>
            <STATUS>B</STATUS>
            <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
            <SOMETHING>fgh</SOMETHING>
        </XYZ>
        <XYZ>
            <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
            <PARENT_ITEM>331-4437</PARENT_ITEM>
            <ITEM>1234</ITEM>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
            <REV>A02-00</REV>
            <STATUS>B</STATUS>
            <ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>B</ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS>
        </XYZ>
    </XYZ>
</ABCD>
```

Comment: So you want to reorder the XYZ elements, basically? I suggest you look at LINQ to XML for how to parse and access XML, and LINQ for ordering. Hint: `var newElements = elements.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...).ThenBy(...)`

Comment: Xml Order doesn't make a difference.   You can sort the results after you parse the sml

Comment: @jdweng: "Xml Order doesn't make a difference." That's nonsense. In *some* applications it may not, in others it certainly does.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. You've given some sample input, but not the expected output. Do you want each XYZ element to be recursively sorted? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Is the `Item` value not even a number? How does "331-4437" sort compared with "3314437" for example? When you say "sort" by level, isn't the level just inherent in terms of the nesting? Likewise isn't the parent item dictated by where it is in the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just sort a recursive structure.  You will loose the hierarchy.  Try following code which uses xml linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication62
{

    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Node(INPUT_FILENAME, OUTPUT_FILENAME);
        }


    }
    public class Node
    {
        public static Node root = new Node();

        public List<Node> children { get; set; }

        public int level { get; set; }
        public string item { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public string rev { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string mostActive { get; set; }

        public Node() { }
        public Node(string in_filename, string out_filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(in_filename);

            XElement xmlRoot = doc.Root;
            GetNodesRecursive(root, xmlRoot);

            SortItemRecursive(root);

            XElement newDoc = new XElement("ABCD");
            GetXmlRecursive(root, newDoc);

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(out_filename, settings);
            writer.WriteRaw(newDoc.ToString());
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
        public void GetNodesRecursive(Node parent, XElement xmlParent)
        {
            foreach (XElement xyz in xmlParent.Elements("XYZ"))
            {
                if (parent.children == null)
                {
                    parent.children = new List<Node>();
                }
                Node newChild = new Node();
                parent.children.Add(newChild);

                newChild.level = (int)xyz.Element("LEVEL");
                newChild.item = (string)xyz.Element("ITEM");
                newChild.qty = (int)xyz.Element("QTY");
                newChild.rev = (string)xyz.Element("REV");
                newChild.status = (string)xyz.Element("STATUS");
                newChild.mostActive = (string)xyz.Element("ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS");

                GetNodesRecursive(newChild, xyz);
            }
        }
        public void GetXmlRecursive(Node parent, XElement xmlParent)
        {
            xmlParent.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement("LEVEL", parent.level),
                new XElement("ITEM", parent.item),
                new XElement("QTY", parent.qty),
                new XElement("REV", parent.rev),
                new XElement("STATUS", parent.status),
                new XElement("ITEM_MOST_ACTIVE_STATUS", parent.mostActive)
            });

            if (parent.children != null)
            {
                foreach (Node node in parent.children)
                {
                    XElement child = new XElement("XYZ");
                    xmlParent.Add(child);
                    GetXmlRecursive(node, child);
                }
            }
        }
        public void SortItemRecursive(Node parent)
        {
            if (parent.children != null)
            {
                parent.children = parent.children.OrderBy(x => x.item).ToList();
                foreach (Node child in parent.children)
                {
                    SortItemRecursive(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. But how do i sort and store in a new XML in the **same structure** where the sequence of child can get changed? If you can please help me with code of sorting and storing part.

Comment: I updated code to read and write.  Any changes made to classes will appear in the output file.  What sorting do you need?

Comment: Just imagine XYZ as one node having some child like level,item,qty,status etc. So now i want to sort each such XYZ node according to the level&item&parentitem in ascending order. i.e the level should go up from 0,1,2,.. and in the same way the item and parent item too.  I hope you got my point.@jdweng . For example - in my above XML the XYZ with level 0 and item 2240123 should become the first node and XYZ node with level 0 and item 331-4437 should come down.

Comment: The question is still unclear as to what the OP is trying to achieve, but when the question is clarified, I expect it will be achievable with much simpler code than this.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have to compare two XML files even if the sequence of child is different and highlight the differences side by side. Suppose in XML1 - we have A,B,C and in XML2 - we have C,A,B then the comparer should not give a mismatch. So to proceed with this project what i thought is if i can sort both the XMLs with respect to some primary keys(level&item&parentitem in my case) and them pass the sorted XML to a line by line comparer then it can produce the desired result. I hope now you know my requirements.

Comment: And the challange over here is the node XYZ can have any number of further XYZ as child nodes. that means XYZ can be a nested one.

Comment: @sourav: All this information should be *in the question*, with the sample output included, along with details - is the nesting important, or would it be feasible to just flatten all the XYZ elements? If you only give vague requirements, you won't get good answers.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the updated code. It works great. But if the number of elements inside an XYZ is not fixed that means LEVEL,ITEM,PARENTITEM will be surely present,but suppose if other elements gets changed then how to tackle it.?

Comment: Order doesn't really make a difference in xml.  Not a normal requirement.

Comment: @jdweng: That's the second time you've stated that, and I don't know where you get the idea from. Take XHTML for example: are you really going to claim that the order of paragraphs on a web page doesn't matter? Every XML API I've ever used make it trivial to access elements *in document order*. If order didn't matter, why would they do that? Sure, it doesn't matter for *all* documents, but claiming it "doesn't really make a difference in XML" is far, far too broad a statement.

Comment: The order of *attributes* within an XML element is not intended to be significant, but that's a different matter.

Comment: In general, an xml file is a database and most database to not store date in order unless it is a specific requirement.  Database are normally designed for speed and not for order.

Comment: @jdweng I actully want to compare two xml files and display the result side by side and highlight the differences out. So can you suggest me some way on how to do that. for test case suppose I have to compare my Input & output file of this question.

Comment: Use BeyondCompare.  You can download for free.  It has a nice feature that will display differences to an html file and show differences.

Comment: @jdweng what if the sequence of child is not same in both the files.? Suppose one file has A,B,C as childs and the other file has B,D,C,A as its child elements.Then what to do.?

Comment: With beyond compare you can manually align to highlight the changes when the automatic mode doesn't give what you need.

Comment: @jdweng cant we recursively sort the XML file by passing the XYZ node as a argument to the sortmethod,without defining the inner tags as methods of object as u did in the code above. because suppose if i dont know the number of tags within an XYZ then how to sort the XML?

Comment: Yes.  The current code starts at the root node.  But if you want to start someplace else the code will still work.

Comment: @jdweng you have initialized root as a static object. So when i try to run the code with two XML files i.e 2 INPUT files , for the second XML file it copies the whole of first one and then the required XML of the 2nd one is intended after that. So can you suggest what can be done to run the same piece of code for more than one INPUT files.?

Comment: Make root a list : public static List<Node> root = new List<Node>();public static Node root = new Node();

Comment: Thanks so much @jdweng. I just nullified the object when the writter file is closed.